# Matlab Compiler Runtime is unable to launch a function from signal processing toolbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-java

I am using a function called "findpeaks" from signal processing toolbox in my source code. The source code is then packed into a jar file to be launched from Java on a different machine. Java invokes MRC to perform its execution which ends with following exception:

> Undefined function 'findpeaks' for input arguments of type 'double'

What could be the possible cause of this exception.?

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? Does your code run fine in MATLAB before compiling?

Comment: Matlab 2014b, yes it does run fine before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I managed to include it this way.

Copy the findpeaks.m and its dependency (chkinputdatatype.m) from SPT to your current directory.

Donot forget to include all the toolboxes used in program while compiling.

Thanks.